# Adding emoticon to comments but not working

Tags: php

I have been trying to add emoticons in comments but it is not working, and I have no idea why.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/content/---------------------------/cdn/postdisplay.php on line 1
```

Full php which i include and load to display comments.

```
<?php
function smiliess($text) {
        $smilies = array(
            '>:('        =>  '<img src="image/icon/angry.png" alt="angry" class="icon_smile1" />',
            '(angry)'    =>  '<img src="image/icon/angry.png" alt="angry" class="icon_smile2" />',
            '(Angry)'    =>  '<img src="image/icon/angry.png" alt="angry" class="icon_smile3" />',
            '(ANGRY)'    =>  '<img src="image/icon/angry.png" alt="angry" class="icon_smile4" />',
            'B|'         =>  '<img src="image/icon/cool.png" alt="cool" class="icon_smile5" />',
            '(cool)'     =>  '<img src="image/icon/cool.png" alt="cool" class="icon_smile6" />',
            '(Cool)'     =>  '<img src="image/icon/cool.png" alt="cool" class="icon_smile7" />',
            '(COOL)'     =>  '<img src="image/icon/cool.png" alt="cool" class="icon_smile8" />',    
            // more smiley
        );  
    foreach ($smilies as $search => $replace)
        $text = preg_replace("#(?<=\s|^)" . preg_quote($search) . "#", $replace, $text);
    return $text;
}
$CheckQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_comment WHERE got='$user->id' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0 , 20");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($CheckQuery))
{
    $toolsp = new UserTools();
    $post = $toolsp->get($row['send_id']);  
    $yourText = $row['content'];
    $yourdisplay = smiliess( $yourText );
    echo '<div class="mycomment">
        <div id="postpic">
            <img id="profile_pic" width="50px" height="150px" src="' . $post->image . '" class="" />
        </div>
        <div class="mycommentpost">                     
            <a class="postername" href="profile.php?userID=' . $post->id . '">' . $post->fname . ' ' . $post->lname . ': </a><br />
            ' . $yourdisplay . '
        </div>
    </div>';
}
?>
```

It works fine when i remove emoticon code from php.

Comment: Have you try this `$text = preg_replace("#(?<=\s|^)" . preg_quote($search) . "#", $replace, $text);
    return $text;` manually for each possibilities, to see if one of them throw an exception?

Comment: yes did but not works i have been trying many ways :(

Comment: By "corrected, but still not working" do you mean "still getting the same error"?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/----------------------/postdisplay.php on line 1

Comment: 1. Do a `var_dump $yourText;` immediately before `$yourdisplay = smiliess( $yourText );` and then a `var_dump $yourdisplay` immediately after. 2. Tell us the first result. 3. Tell us if you got a second result prior to the error, and if so, what was the second result.

Answer (score 2):

You have called your array `$smilies` when you declare it but are calling it in your foreach loop as `$smiles`.

Answer (score 2):

you have `;` here remove it

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($CheckQuery));
                                            ^
```

and change your query also

```
$CheckQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_comment WHERE got='" . $user->id . "' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0 , 20");
```